# How to remove checkbox for GDPR in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, login, validation, checkbox, gdpr

I want to remove GDPR checkbox in Magento 2 Login Page.
[image]

I want to remove that checkbox from login page
it will come from ( app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_child/MGS_GDPR/templates/customer/form/login.phtml ) this file but the validation on this observer ( app/code/MGS/GDPR/Observer/CheckUserLoginObserver.php )

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    $loginParams = $controller->getRequest()->getPost('login');

    if ($this->_helper->getStoreConfig('gdpr/general/active') 
        && $this->_helper->getStoreConfig('gdpr/login/active') 
        && !isset($loginParams['accept_gdpr'])) {
        
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('You do not agree with the storage and handling of your data by this website.'));
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $beforeUrl = $this->_session->getBeforeAuthUrl();
        $url = $beforeUrl ? $beforeUrl : $this->_customerUrl->getLoginUrl();
        $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
    }

    return;
}
```

This method is used for validation so i want to know how to extend it in child theme and how to pass this validation or is there any other way to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The extension provides functionality to show/hide GDPR checkbox on login page itself. So instead of removing it through code, you can just disable it from backend.

Go to `Stores -> Configuration -> MGS -> GDPR -> Login Form-> Show Checkbox` and set it **NO**

Refer [this](https://www.magesolution.com/magento2-gdpr.html) for more details. Thanks!

Comment: @Prits is my answer worked for you?

Comment: @Prits Is it worked for you?